# scrapy LxmlLinkExtractor to crawl relative urls

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to crawl all the relative urls under tag in http://news.qq.com/

the code of mine is that:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector  
from homework.items import HomeworkItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor

class News1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "News1"
    allowed_domains = ["http://news.qq.com/"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://news.qq.com/',
    )
    rules = (
        Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="Q-   tpList"]/div/a/@href'),callback='parse'),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
    #lis = sel.xpath('//div[@class="Q-tpList"]')
    #item = TutorialItem()
    #for li in lis:
        title = sel.xpath('//div[@id=C-Main-Article-QQ]/div[1]/text()').extract()
        content =sel.xpath('//div[@id=Cnt-Main-Article-QQ]/p/text()').extract()
        print title
```

when running cmd scrapy crawl News1

I cant get the title in command window ,Could you please tell me how to revise it and why?  thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're subclassing `Spider`, but since you have `start_urls`, I think you meant to use `CrawlSpider`. In this case, you need to revise your structure, since `parse` is actually used internally by `CrawlSpider` to find new links to crawl:

```
rules = (
    Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="Q-   tpList"]/div/a/@href'), callback='parse_page'),
)

def parse_page(self, response):
    ...
```

You should fix this class name and remove the spaces as well:

```
//div[@class="Q-   tpList"]/div/a/@href
                ^^^
```

Finally, I think you're using an old version of Scrapy. I suggest you upgrade now before writing more code using the old API, since it'll be harder to switch later.

Comment: @Blender `start_urls` is not `CrawlSpider` exclusive, maybe you've meant `rules`? Since that is an exclusive parameter to CrawlSpider.

Comment: @Blender I have revised my code as you said , but still not work~ is there any possibility for me to get an error LxmlLinkExtractor restrict_xpaths?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you are either using an outdate scrapy version or having bad imports since right now scrapy has only 1 type of link extractors - LinkExtractor (which is renamed LxmlExtractor)

I've tested this and it works perfectly fine:

```
$ scrapy shell 'http://news.qq.com/'
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=['//div[@class="Q-tpList"]/div/a']).extract_links(response)
# got 43 results
```

Note no spaces in xpath `@class` check and it points to `a` node rather than `@href` attribute because LinkExtractor extract nodes not parameters.